# How to make the same button hide and show the block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<button class="my_btn btn-success">Hide and Show</button></p>
<h1 id="hol">Hello World</h1>



$(".my_btn").on('click', function(event) {
    $("#hol").hide();
});
```

How to make the same button hide and show the hol block?
plz help, i am beginning developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [**`.toggle()`**](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) that will *display or hide the matched elements*:

```js
$(".my_btn").on('click', function(event) {
    $("#hol").toggle();
    // you can set the specific text for the button as well
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="my_btn btn-success">Hide</button></p>
<h1 id="hol">Hello World</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `toggle` to switch between hide and show